# Intuition of Homogenous Equations in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Ax = 0

A is the function, a matrix that performs linear transformation on the input vector.

B is the input vector.

0 is the output vector, specifically the zero vector.

Collectively, the equation asks, "What vector input, when linearly transformed, results in a zero vector?" In regular algebra, it would be similar to asking, "for what values of x, makes f(x) = 0 true?"

1. What is the equivalent of the horizontal asymptote in linear algebra? My guess is the origin.
2. Linear transformations modify the space and changes the grid basis. But geometrically, how can there be two vectors that when modified result in the same zero vector? Does that mean space sort of collapses on itself? Or, instead of an original, the horizontal asymptote in linear algebra is almost like that in regular algebra: a line where output is 0, and input doesn't matter (e.g. (4,0) and (8,0) are both horizontal asymptotes because y = 0 in both cases)?

---

For Ax = 0 to have a non-trivial solution, one that's not where x is a zero vector, there has to be a free variable.

For there to be a free variable, then there must be less pivots than rows in the coefficient matrix.

3. Basically why there needs to be a free variable is so that the solution set for Ax=b can "shift" along that variable axis to also include b=0, correct?

---

The geometric visualization of Ax=0 can be dumbed down to essentially be three planes with intersections all at (0,0,0). Solving for Ax=b is asking whether all the linear equations intersect at b, for which b=0 is a specific case. So then why is b=0 important?

I get that, if you solve for Ax=0, then solutions of Ax=b are just translations of the solution for Ax=0.

4. Can't we just pick another point to solve for, and translate those solutions to fit the new solution sets for Ax=b?

---

5. Linear transformations can collapse the solution set, as in take the vector from R^n to R^n-1 if the columns of A are linearly dependent. But can the solution set be expanded from R^n to R^n+1?

Comment: Regarding question 4: no! The set of solutions to $Ax=0$ (called the *kernel* of A) is special because solutions to $Ax=b$ for nonzero $b$ differ by homogeneous solutions. In other words, given $x_1, x_2$ such that $Ax_1=b$ and $Ax_2=b$, then $0=b-b=Ax_1-Ax_2=A(x_1-x_2)$, so $x_1-x_2$ is a solution of the homogeneous system. This trick won't work if you "pick another point to solve for" besides $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, A is not a function in this context. However, we can describe a certain transformation T such that T(x) = Ax (i.e. defined by the matrix).

Q1. What is the equivalent of the horizontal asymptote in linear algebra? My guess is the origin.

A1. "The horizontal asymptote" is too ambiguous. Perhaps if you can elaborate there, I can provide an answer.

Q2.  But geometrically, how can there be two vectors that when modified result in the same zero vector? Does that mean space sort of collapses on itself?

A2. There are not always two vectors that result in a zero vector after a transformation. Sometimes there are more, sometimes there are less; it depends on a property of the matrix we call the "Null Space". The null space tells which vectors are transformed into the zero vector. (The vectors x such that Ax = 0.) Often times we can think of the null space as the "collapsing" of our initial space, the domain. Loosely speaking, if we "lose" dimensions during the transformation, then we are "losing" vectors to the null space. Also, I should end this portion by saying that it is not usual for only 2 vectors to be in the null space of a matrix. More often there are usually one (the zero vector: A(0) = 0) or infinitely many. However, a more appropriate way to describe it would be with the dimension of the null space, often called the "nullity".

Q3. Basically why there needs to be a free variable is so that the solution set for Ax=b can "shift" along that variable axis to also include b=0, correct?

A3. I don't understand what you're asking here, but again elaboration may help. You should look into pre-established analogies for things like these in linear algebra.

Q4. Can't we just pick another point to solve for, and translate those solutions to fit the new solution sets for Ax=b?

A4. This may be possible in some cases; however, it is neither efficient or useful (in general). The equation Ax = 0 is important because of properties such as nullity, rank (Rank-Nullity Theorem), eigenvalues, eigenvectors, one-to-one, etc...

Q5. Linear transformations can collapse the solution set, as in take the vector from R^n to R^n-1 if the columns of A are linearly dependent. But can the solution set be expanded from R^n to R^n+1?

A5. Yes, they can collapse with a null space as I describe previously. As I will show, the dimension (of the co-domain!) can increase as well. Allow me to illustrate this final answer with a matrix A whose dimension is k by p. Consider the vectors in its domain (you should see that they are all p by 1 column vectors, or p-dimensional). What dimension is the co-domain? $(k,p) * (p,1) = (k,1)$ The dimension is k! So all that is required for the dimension (from the domain to the co-domain) to increase is to have k > p. Equivalently stated, the matrix A should have more rows than columns.

***Note: Above I say "co-domain" and not "range". My apologies for the misconstruing of your question. It should be noted that it is not possible for a linear transformation to increase its range from the dimension of its domain. This is because the null space always contains at least the zero vector (See again rank-nullity theorem). Thanks to @amd for pointing this out.***

Comment: Your answer to Q5 seems to be missing an important point. Although it’s true that the codomain of a linear map can be of any dimension, including one greater than that of the domain, the image of the map—its output—can’t have a greater dimension than that of its input.

Comment: @amd Thank you, I've edited my response. Let me know if my statement in the note about the rank-nullity theorem is correct; I feel uneasy about it.

Comment: You probably don’t need to invoke the rank-nullity theorem for this. Linearity of the operator should be enough to ensure that the image of a vector space has at most the same dimension: that image is spanned by the images of the basis vectors.

Comment: Response to Q1: I would suppose 'null space' would be the equivalent of horizontal asymptote, or x-axis, in linear algebra, as that's answers to f(x) = 0 and Ax=0 reside -- sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Response to Q3: I was trying to say that the free variable allows for 'flexibility' as you can plug in any real number (?) and the equation Ax=b would still hold true, even if b = 0.